# How to create a hidden property at runtime

Tags: powershell, class, properties, hidden

I'm trying to create a powershell class with readonly properties, that each have a getter that reads their hidden counterpart (Property1 >> _Property1)
This part works fine, but I'm unable to hide _Property1

I included the stripped down code below - the actual code retrieves the property/values from a database.

Anybody knows how to hide a property at runtime ?

```bsh
cls
Class TestClass
{
    TestClass()
    { 
        # List of properties to create
        # at runtime, this is retrieved from a database table
        $DBResult = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{'Property1' = 'value1' ; 'Property2' = 'value2' ; 'Property3' = 'value3'}

        # Create readonly properties
        foreach ($Name in ($DBResult | Get-Member -MemberType Properties).Name)
        {
            $Getter = [ScriptBlock]::Create("return `$this._$Name")
            $Setter = [ScriptBlock]::Create("Write-Warning ""'$Name' is a readonly property !""")

            write-host "Getter[$Getter]" -ForegroundColor Yellow
            write-host "Setter[$Setter]" -ForegroundColor Yellow
            write-host ("hidden [string]`$_{0} = '{1}'" -f $Name, $DBResult."$Name")

            # Create the hidden property at runtime - how ?
            $this | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "_$Name" -Value $DBResult."$Name"
            #Invoke-Expression ("hidden [string]`$_{0} = '{1}'" -f $Name, $DBResult."$Name")

            # Create the visible read/only property
            $this | Add-Member -MemberType ScriptProperty -Name $Name -Value $Getter -SecondValue $Setter
        }
    }
}

$Test = [TestClass]::new()
$Test | fl -Property *
```

Comment: Even `hidden` properties aren't private.  They are visible when using `Get-Member -Force`

Comment: That's no problem. It's the responsibility of the programmer to not mess around with the hidden properties. As long as they are not listed without using -force

Answer (score 2):

kudos to Avalon77

Your code is csharp oriented and not very suitable for my project, but it gave me the idea to build the class with string and feed it to Invoke-Expression.
It is not clean, but until powershell allows to add a hidden member (Add-Member), this will do :

```bsh
cls
$DBResult = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{'Property1' = 'value1' ; 'Property2' = 'value2' ; 'Property3' = 'value3'}

Invoke-Expression -Command @"
Class TestClass
{
    # Create the hidden property
$(  $DBResult | Get-Member -MemberType Properties | ForEach-Object { "`thidden `$_{0} = '{1}'`n" -f $_.Name, $DBResult."$($_.Name)" } )

    TestClass()
    { 
        # Create the visible read/only property
$(  $DBResult | Get-Member -MemberType Properties | ForEach-Object {
        "`t`t`$this | Add-Member -MemberType ScriptProperty -Name '{0}' -Value {1} return `$this._{0} {2} -SecondValue {1} Write-Warning '[{0}] is a Readonly property !' {2}`n" -f $_.Name, '{', '}'
    }
)
    }
}
"@

$Test = [TestClass]::new()
$Test | fl -Property *

$Test.Property1 = 'try to change readonly value'
$Test._Property1 = 'changed value'
$Test | fl -Property *
```

the result of this string building is :

```bsh
Class TestClass
{
    # Create the hidden property
    hidden $_Property1 = 'value1'
    hidden $_Property2 = 'value2'
    hidden $_Property3 = 'value3'


    TestClass()
    { 
        # Create the visible read/only property
        $this | Add-Member -MemberType ScriptProperty -Name 'Property1' -Value { return $this._Property1 } -SecondValue { Write-Warning '[Property1] is a Readonly property !' }
        $this | Add-Member -MemberType ScriptProperty -Name 'Property2' -Value { return $this._Property2 } -SecondValue { Write-Warning '[Property2] is a Readonly property !' }
        $this | Add-Member -MemberType ScriptProperty -Name 'Property3' -Value { return $this._Property3 } -SecondValue { Write-Warning '[Property3] is a Readonly property !' }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this ?

```
$DBResults = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{'Property1' = 'value1' ; 'Property2' = 'value2' ; 'Property3' = 'value3'}

$ClassName = "TestClass"

$ClassDeclaration = "public class $ClassName"
$ClassDeclaration += [System.Environment]::NewLine
$ClassDeclaration += "{"
$TestString = ""

$PropertyList = @()

foreach ($Name in ($DBResults | Get-Member -MemberType Properties).Name)
{
    $Value = $DBResult."$Name"
    $ClassDeclaration += $([System.Environment]::NewLine)
    $ClassDeclaration += "private string @$("_" + $Name) = `"$Value`";"
    $ClassDeclaration += $([System.Environment]::NewLine)
    $ClassDeclaration += "public string @$("get" + $Name) { get { return $("_" + $Name); } }"
}

$ClassDeclaration += $([System.Environment]::NewLine)
$ClassDeclaration += "}"

$FinalClassDefinition = @"
    $ClassDeclaration
"@

try {Add-Type -Language CSharp -TypeDefinition $FinalClassDefinition -IgnoreWarnings} catch { return $_.Exception.Message }

$Test = [TestClass]::new()
$Test  | fl -Property *
```

The parsing doesn't seem to work but the code well ;-)